# Change checkbox tickmark color

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I've implemented a function to change the background color of my checkbox , but it makes the tickmark turns to color black which I don't want , I want the mark to still white , how can I achieve this ?

HTML :-

```
<div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
     <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="categoryInput" @change="input()" 
        :true-value="category.id" false-value="0" v-model="currentCategory"/>
        <label class="form-label">{{category.name}}</label>
      </div>
</div>
```

here's the function :-

```
input(){
        var color = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coloring') || '[]').CTAButtons
        let collection = document.getElementsByClassName("categoryInput");
        for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        collection[i].style.accentColor = color
        }
    }
```

and here's the output :-
[image]
the background changed successfully but the tickmark changed to color black

Comment: Do you have CSS and HTML to go with this JS?

Comment: @Millhorn there's no css , i added the html above

Comment: The default behavior does not change the color. https://jsfiddle.net/1L0w8ray/  You need to check your global css

Comment: I'm not a vue developer, so I'm likely going to get this wrong. There's a simple tutorial on how to change checkbox styles (w3schools). As @AlaksandarJesusGene mentioned... checking your global CSS - [Custom Checkboxes](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox)

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene it works fine when i put a fixed color as you did in the fiddle , the wrong behavior happens when i get this color from local storage , although it returns "#3bb0a8"

Comment: If you pass the color value as hexadecimal,the tick mark goes to black. If you pass the color name, the tick mark  shows white...  Why not you try to store the color name and instead of hexadecimal code. I would recommend to use icons where you get more controls

Comment: Here is the reason. If you darker background, you will see white tickmark. If you go light background, you will see black tickmark. You need to pick a background color which is darker.. check with different colors here.. https://jsfiddle.net/2pqb8uf9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tickmark color for the default HTML checkbox is decided by the browser and cannot be changed.  You can however [create your own custom checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) and style it however you want.

HTML

```html
<label class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

CSS

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a teal background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #3bb0a8;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1yb7wsp/)

Comment: this solution will not work with me 'cause I'm not using fixed background-color value

Comment: This is just to get the custom checkbox set up.  You can still override the CSS with similar JS to what you have now...  [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tc53ok04/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of going with vue is to build custom components. So you can try something as shown below.

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-aweuze)

You might want to tweak your code depending on your exact requirement.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
    <div>
      <label class="form-label categoryInput">
        <span class="material-icons icon" v-if="isChecked(category.id)"
          >check_box</span
        >
        <span
          class="material-icons-outlined icon"
          v-if="!isChecked(category.id)"
          >check_box_outline_blank</span
        >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          class=""
          @change="input()"
          :value="category.id"
          v-model="currentCategory"
        />
        {{ category.name }}</label
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Checkbox',
  data: function () {
    return {
      currentCategory: [],
      categories: [
        { id: 1, name: 'alpha' },
        { id: 2, name: 'beta' },
      ],
    };
  },
  props: {},
  methods: {
    isChecked(categoryId) {
      return this.currentCategory.indexOf(categoryId) !== -1;
    },
    input() {
      var color = '#3bb0a8';
      let collection = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryInput');
      for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        const icons = collection[i].querySelectorAll('.icon');
        icons.forEach((iconEle) => {
          iconEle.style.color = color;
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
label.categoryInput {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
label.categoryInput input[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
</style>
```

**Important**

Add below to your index.html header

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```